# R Reactable highlight entire rows based on condition

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, reactable

I want to highlight all rows in a `reactable` that meet a certain condition.
Unfortunately, I have found neither an option nor a suggested solution for this on the net.

Here is my reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

mtcars %>% 
  reactable(striped = TRUE)
```

[image]

In this example, all rows where the `cyl`-value is 4 should be highlighted in yellow.

```
df_example <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(backgorud_color = ifelse(cyl == 4 , "yellow", "grey"))
```

Can anyone help me with the configuration of the `reactable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [Conditional Styling](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/conditional-styling.html) vignette you can conditionally set the background color using a custom rendering function like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

mtcars %>%
  reactable(
    striped = TRUE,
    rowStyle = function(index) {
      if (mtcars[index, "cyl"] == 4) {
        list(background = "yellow")
      }
    }
  )
```

[image]

Comment: You entered your answer a few seconds after I found the same solution myself. :)
However, I would make the following line more dynamic. `mtcars`can also be replaced by a dot: `if (mtcars[index, "cyl"] == 4)` to `if (.[index, "cyl"] == 4)`
See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out that there is the `rowStyle`-option in the `reactable`-function.
See https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/conditional-styling.html

```
mtcars %>% 
  reactable(
    rowStyle = function(index) {
      if (.[index, "cyl"] == 4) {
        list(background = "yellow")
      }
    }
  )
```

[image]